# Machine learning preprocess strings to numbers based on string similarity

Tags: string, algorithm, machine-learning, similarity

I need to preprocess data into numbers in order to be able to apply ML algorithms in a dataset, but there is this feature that is almost Tree structured with strings which I have no idea how to transform. Here goes an example:

```
Feature -> Value I would like to transform to (example):

X Y Z foo -> 0.5
X Y Z bar -> 0.501

A B C foo -> 4.1
W B C foo -> 5
```

Essentially the string would transform into a unique real number, where this number would be really close to other numbers if their strings were almost identical, giving greater weights to the first words that come up first on the String.

My question, is there an already existing algorithm to solve this?

Comment: You are asking to embed a higher dimensional space in a 1 dimensional space. That's usually impossible except approximately. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction for pointers, but you'll also have to decide what your distance metric is.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I do not know any algorithm to solve this. But I have an idea (I know this is not "an answer" but I lack the reputation to add this as a comment).

Transform every string by repeating every character proportional to their position from the end. For example, "Foo" will become "FFFooo" and "abcd" "aaaabbbccd". Then use the [edit-distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) over every pair to build a distance matrix, M.

Now it is an optimization problem. Start with random solution (a random real to every word), then calculate the distance matrix M' of your solution and minimize some metric (squared error) between M and M'.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me from your example that you are trying to find the similarity between two document of texts. Cosine similarity is the most widely used distance measure in this context.

For instance, let us compare "The boy eats the apple" and "The girl eats the pear"

First, create a frequency matrix, where entry ij contains the number of times term j is contained in document i.

```
              "the"  "boy"   "girl"  "eats"  "apple"  "pear"
(sentence 1)    2       1      0       1        1        0
(sentence 2)    2       0      1       1        0        1
```

The cosine similarity can thus be calculated with

[image]

From [Principles of Data Mining](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/principles-data-mining):

> This is the cosine of the anvgle between the two vectors (equivalently, their inner product after each has been normalized to have unit length) and, thus, reflects similarity in terms of the relative distribution of their term components.